# MKMapView shows user location not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, maps

I have a MKMapView . In the attribute inspector of MKMapView i checked shows user location option and i run the app . But it not showing user location .Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your running the app in the simulator then you need to turn on the user location simulation. You can turn it on by either clicking the little location arrow just above the debug console in Xcode or you can enable a more customizable location in the simulator by going to Debug > Location > Custom Location...